# 60 amp Fuse box as junction box for 150a panel

Tags: electrical-panel

Electrician in PA wants to use old 60amp FEDERAL fuse box panel (which happens to be in bathroom wall, less than 3 feet from sink and shower) as junction Box to new 150 or 200 amp panel which will be less than 12 feet away from old fuse panel. I say NO WAY! Wont pass inspection to get us electric turned back on (been vacant) and besides, it is just plain dangerous! Please settle this argument.  Opens in bathroom, literally an arms length across from shower. I dont know specifics if he going to gut old panel. Perhaps thats what he was thinking. I pictured it as running thru old panel to new. But if using just empty metal box w lid screwed shut, it seems a little safer as long as splicing to a larger amp panel is ok... rest of wiring still intact in house  but we would like to upgrade and run new wiring after we get some power out there.

Comment: Is the old panel just being used as an empty box to join wires? Does it open *into* the bathroom or is it just mounted in that wall and opens outside?

Comment: I take it the electrician is removing the panelboard (fuse box guts) from the old fuse box cabinet (enclosure)?  Is the electrician routing branch circuit wiring, the service wires, or both through this box?  How many circuits are going through the box in question, and what size is it, anyway?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I've edited out your second question; please ask it separately. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: There is nothing in code that prevents a junction box from being in a bathroom. Every receptacle and light have a box and some are much closer than 3’ to the basin. I agree with George’s answer it will pass code.

Comment: Why do you believe that this would be dangerous/not pass inspection where you're at?

Answer (score 2):

It is fairly typical to use an old panel box with the guts removed for use as a junction box. Once the work is done, the cover plate can be screwed down to prevent opening while still being "permanently accessible".  If you don't like to appearance, hang a picture over it! But it will pass code in most places.

Comment: Code even allows panels designed for removal if it doesn’t damage the structure or finish. For many years I have put frames held in place with Velcro to hide boxes , an inspector liked my method but mentioned it is allowed to screw the frames in , I have been doing it this way for decades including in bathrooms.

Answer (score 0):

USA Code allows splices inside breaker/fuse panels, so this would be legit even if the fuses were retained.

The panel having been put in the bathroom a living age ago, is surely **grandfathered** and is legal today because it was legal when installed.  **Merely having the building be vacant does not zero out grandfathering**.  It might if during the vacancy all the wiring had been gutted by copper thieves etc.

Comment: Thank you all. Looks like thats the way it will be, at least temporarily to get power on to do some actual work there. I have to tell my husb he wins this one. ;)

Answer (score 0):

### Gutting a cabinet to use as a junction box is A-OK; they just can't leave the fuse blocks in it

The key to understanding what your electrician is likely proposing is that a panelboard (the technical term for fuse panels, breaker boxes, loadcenters, and such) consists of two parts: an *interior* that holds the fuses or breakers and busbars, then mounts to a *cabinet* that encloses the interior, overcurrent devices, and attached wiring, complete with cover and door.

As a result of this distinction, which is both historical (panelboards back in the day were built up in the field from individual fuse blocks, busbars, and a cabinet) and practical (you can put in the cabinet and run conduits to it during roughin, then return with the interior once all the finish work's done so it doesn't get gooped with drywall mud, paint, texture, or other worksite contaminants), there are not one, but *two* UL standards that apply.  Panelboards are built and tested to UL 67, while the cabinet standing alone are constructed to meet a *different* UL standard, namely UL 50. Thing is, UL 50 is a generic standard that covers a variety of different types of electrical boxes, including the junction box's bigger brother, the *pull box*.

As a result of this, and the fact that splices are generally legal in panelboard cabinets to begin with (NEC 312.6), it is generally considered permissible during a service upgrade to remove the interior from a panelboard cabinet and reuse the cabinet as a junction/pull box to feed the new wiring.  Note that in this case, they can't leave the interior intact because overcurrent devices can't be installed in a bathroom (240.24(E)); however, with the interior removed, that's no longer an issue.  Also, best practice when doing this is to replace the existing cover with a piece of suitably thick (17 gauge or thicker, as per 312.11(B)) sheet steel that's been painted whatever color is called for; barring that, your AHJ may accept simply having the door on the existing cover screwed shut to keep someone from opening it and thus being able to poke live parts through the door holes that once provided access to the fuse blocks.